# Increase in "table lookup" on old Postfix/PostgreSQL installation

Tags: debian, postfix, postgresql

The box is still running PostgreSQL 8.1 and this started to increase a few weeks ago. It is only happening while the server is a bit busy.

```
fatal: pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup problem
fatal: pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup problem
fatal: pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup problem
```

No other changes where made, so it seems to be related to a load increase. A new upgrade Debian Jessie box is in the works, but is there anything I can do in the meantime?

Comment: Look for any error in the server logs  under `/var/log/postgresql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was all related to more load on the mail server. Upping the number of PostGreSQL connections in the config, solved this problem for me.